# Nuxtjs how to add global environment variable in all sass files

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, node-sass

I want to load an environment variable in all my `sass`/`scss` files.

What I have done so far in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  ...
  loaders: {
    scss: {
      data: '$myenv: ' + process.env.MY_ENV + ';'
    }
  }
}
```

and I got this error in `mystyle.scss`:

> Undefined variable: "$myenv".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loaders` config belongs under the [`build`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build) property (not the root as you have it). If your project was generated with [`create-nuxt-app`](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app), the default `nuxt.config.js` already contains a `build` property at the bottom of the object, so you could move your `loaders` config into that property.

*Example (tested with Nuxt CLI v2.12.2):*

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  build: {
    loaders: {
      scss: {
        data: '$myenv: ' + process.env.MY_ENV + ';'

        // use `prependData` for sass-loader > 7.x
        //prependData: '$myenv: ' + process.env.MY_ENV + ';'
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: moving `loaders` config inside `build` property did the trick. but changing `data` to `prependData` caused the same problem.

Comment: I'm using `sass-loader v7.1.0`. based on [vue loader document](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sharing-global-variables): use `data` if sass-loader version < 8

Comment: i'm on sass-loader > 8, and I have to use "additionalData".

Answer (score 2):

For Nuxt js:

```
build: {
   loaders: {
     scss: {
       additionalData: `$MAIN_COLOR: ${process.env.NUXT_MAIN_COLOR};`,
     },
   },
 },
```

In nuxt.config.js

Comment: if you have lots to define you can do: `additionalData: '@import "~/assets/scss/variables.scss";'`

Answer (score 0):

For `nuxt@2.15.3` and `sass-loader@10.1.1` I have had to use this configuration (*nuxt.config.js*). Notice the use of `sass` instead of `scss` inside `loaders`:

```
export default {
  // ...,

  build: {
    loaders: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `$main-color: ${process.env.MCOL}`
      }
    }
  }
}
```