# Vue.js/NuxtJS - how to create components with a default design customizable by a JSON configuration file

Tags: javascript, css, json, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm developing a NuxtJS website and the pages/components can have either a generic design by default, either one that is customizable by client, and will be specified in the url.

Something alone the lines of:

`http://localhost:3000/registration` - For a generic page

`http://localhost:3000/client-name/registration` - Client specific page

To achieve that goal, I have a JSON configuration file per client (say `client-name.json`) that has this structure.

```
{
  "some_configuration_property": {},
  "another_configuration_property": {},
  "design": {
    "logoUrl": "/assets/client-name/logo.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "primaryColor": "#ffffff",
    "secondaryColor": "#ffff00"
  },
}
```

To start things, I implemented the routing system and I can successfully read each client's configuration based on the current route (inside the `<script>` tag of the Vue file of that route), inside the setup method (I use @nuxt/composition-api).

The problem that I'm facing now is to figure out how to pass these "design variables" into the `<style>` tag of my Vue file, which uses SCSS. The behaviour that I wanted to implement was to have a default design for a specific component/page, but that could be overridden by these "design variables" specific to each client.

- The first thing that came to my mind was to use CSS variables, that
  would allow me to create variables with a default values but that I
  would be able to override inside the styles. I created a sample component for test and it worked with CSS properties and the v-deep pseudo element. However, this means that I would have to create a class for each client in the customized component and that's what I'd like to avoid. I first thought to this approach because it would give me a lot of flexibility about how I choose to use these design colors inside the styles.

Example:

```
// From the customizable component
.my-button {
   color: (--button-color, teal);
}

// Styling from a parent component/view
// Had to create a selector with a style like <div> for superior specificity though, not so clean
v::deep {
  div {
    &.my-button {
      --button-color: purple;
    }
  }
}
```

- I've seen the `/deep/` selector or `::v-deep` pseudo selector but I don't think it's a very clean solution since it would be used a lot in the codebase. Styling component from parents would make the code hardly maintainable.
- Another approach could be to pass a variable, `classArray` for instance, inside the setup method to dynamically bind CSS classes on the DOM elements. Although, it would be way too cumbersome to create a CSS class per client with the associated styles.

Like this:

```
<template>
  <my-button :class="classArray"></my-button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyPage',
  setup() {
    const clientName = 'someClientName';
    const classArray = [clientName]
    return { classArray };
  },
})
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.someClientName {
  // some custom styles
}
</style>
```

What would be your approach in this situation?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow the problem with CSS vars parent/child. But you'll loose SASS features this way (color manipulation, etc). The most hassle-free way is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62370457/nuxtjs-how-to-add-global-environment-variable-in-all-sass-files .

Comment: I already use nuxt-style-resources to have globally defined Sass variables! But that doesn't explain how I could create generic code for each client, I would have to create specific styles in each page or component right? Or do you have another approach in mind?

Comment: Yes, I meant that this needs to compile the app per client, which is probably not what you was hoping for but likely the only option that doesn't use CSS vars. Can you clarify the problem with CSS vars? You can define them dynamically on config load with `setProperty`, then they can be used with SASS function e.g. `primaryColor()`  that generates something like `var(--primary-color, $defaultPrimaryColor)`.

Comment: I made CSS properties work together with v-deep! But the problem is still that I'd have to create a class for each client in the customized component and that's what I'd like to avoid. Are you talking about this setProperty though ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript

Comment: Edited my answer to add CSS vars working code

Comment: Deep selectors look cumbersome and doesn't make use of SASS for theming. Yes, that's what I meant. What I suggest is to still use SASS, only that you need to use functions like primaryColor() instead of using variables like $primaryColor directly. And --primary-color, etc are defined for the whole document at runtime with setProperty.

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example so it's easier to understand? `setProperty` is used to define inline styles on an element, isn't it better to define those CSS properties in a global SCSS file on the `:root` attribute?

Comment: I don't understand how you would customize a component for a specific client with your solution. OK, you're using SASS function to return `var(--primary-color, $defaultPrimaryColor)`, but if `--primary-color` is defined on the document, that doesn't solve my problem because it can't be specific to a URL as I explained in my answer. On the contrary, I want to be able to override `--primary-color` from the a parent component `style` tag.

Comment: Please, clarify why you need to do this per component. The question seems to refer to global client theme. Any way, a variable can be defined on any element in DOM as it's cascading like other styles.

Comment: *isn't it better to define those CSS properties in a global SCSS file on the :root attribute?* - it is, but you don't have these properties at build time. Unless you want to rebuild SCSS on the fly per page, which is not a good idea in production, vars need to be set dynamically as soon as they are available, i.e. when a config is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If custom theme configuration needs to be loaded at runtime, this requires to use CSS variables (properties). They can be wrapped in SCSS functions and have default theme fallbacks:

```
// theme.scss
$primaryColor: #abc;
// $buttonColor: $primaryColor

@function primaryColor() {
  @return #{var(--primary-color, $primaryColor)}
}

@function buttonColor() {
  @return #{var(--button-color, primaryColor())}
}
```

Then `primaryColor()`, etc are used instead of direct use of `$primaryColor`, etc like it's done in regular SCSS theme:

```
// From the customizable component
.my-button {
   color: buttonColor();
}
```

And custom theme can be applied on load to the entire document or a part of it (a hierarchy of components) that should be affected by custom theme:

```
const config = await loadClientConfig();
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(--primary-color, config.design.primaryColor)
```

Comment: I didn't understand your solution correctly, now I get it, thanks for sharing your perspective!